# How to update a html content while I'm executing a process in a sentence while with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How I update the DOM in html meanwhile I'm executing a "while sentece".
Look the example below

```xhtml
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="element" >
    <input type="submit" id ="run" value="run">

    <script>
    function contar(){

        var contador=0;
        while( contador<10){

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#element').val( contador );
            },1000);
                            //I use sleep or setTimeout to try to see the values
                            //if put its in the input.
            console.log("contando");
            contador++;
        }
    }
    function sleep(seconds){
        var e = new Date().getTime() + (seconds * 1000);
         while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {
         }
    }

    $('#run').bind('click',contar);


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Context:**

I have a process logic inside a while loop, this process, generates data that I use to show in a view through of jquery or other way.  When I try to update the content in real time, it's mean  that  when I try to change  some value inside a while loop, it does not  work .All I see is  the last value that generates the process logic. So  I wanna  see all  changing  data.

For example in the code above, I would like see 1 ,2,3,.., value to value.

Comment: Don't. Use callbacks and `setTimeout`.

Comment: FYI, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: sorry the double id, is a mistake the publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your code is, that your while loop

```
while(contador<10){  

    setTimeout(function(){
         $('#element').val( contador );
    },1000);

    contador++;
}
```

will start the inner function `$('#element').val( contador );` 10 times with the same delay of 1000ms instead of executing each code after next 1000ms. 
The reason for this is, that your program won't wait for 1000ms when calling `setTimeout();` - it just starts an other "thread-like" thing, which will be executed after 1000ms. But the program itself will continue straight.

so I think you're looking for something like:

```
    // note these extra function
function updateValue(val){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#element').val( val );
    },1000 * val);
}

  . . .

var contador = 0;
while(contador<10){  
    updateValue(contador);
    contador++;
}
```

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhBU9/)

The extra function is needed to be sure that the right number is printed. If you do it in place inside the while loop, the number will always be your maximum.

Comment: Sorry, but not works, don't update the html content in real time.

Comment: I think I did not get the point of your problem. Please explain again.